# How to use grounded European plug of coffee maker correctly in middle east countries?

Tags: appliances, outlets, grounding

I have bought a coffee maker with a European plug which doesn't have a grounding pin like our **[plugs here in Israel have](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets#Israel_SI32)**. Here is a picture of the splitter I use and the European power plug:

[image]

As seen here, Israeli power outlets have a grounding hole at the bottom as opposed to the grounding pin at the top protruding from european outlets and this creates a dilemma. If the grounding hole was located at the top, I could modify the European plug to attach a pin in order to ground the appliance, but in my situation I can't.

Is there a way around this? What can be done to accomplish what I want?

**UPDATE:** I have recalled that I already had old coffee maker with Israeli plug, look:

[image]
[image]

Should I cut new coffee maker's wire where plug EU begins and then attach old coffee maker's plug? Or I should disassemble new coffee maker, find wire's beginning in coffee maker's base and completely cut wire later replacing it with old coffee maker's wire?

Another question I had is what if to **recreate pin** in EU plug and **turn EU plug upside down** so it can be connected to Israeli socket like this:

[image]

Of course N and L will switch places however.

Comment: Excellently composed question. We should use this as a template for new users. +eleventy.

Comment: @Tester101 Why you removed "Thanks" in the end of my original question? I should not thank people?

Comment: @ChrisCudmore My question was edited by **Tester101** so you should compliment him/her.

Comment: @Boris_yo Your question was great before my edits, I simply added a few "a"'s and "the"'s.  As for removing the "thanks". If you'd like to thank people for helping, give them a [reputation](http://diy.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) boost by upvoting their answers, and/or by accepting the answer that is correct (or most correct in your situation).

Comment: Things like signatures, "thanks", "I hope someone can help me" and other non-useful text is routinely removed from posts to reduce the noise and clutter. This site is a reference as well as a forum. Please don't take the edits personally. They are done to improve the content for everyone. And as @Tester101 said, voting up good answers is a great way to say thanks.

Comment: @Starfish Right, this system is incentive based unlike common forums where function "Thanks" doesn't do more than to count them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The how would be to find an adapter that accepts and properly grounds a French CEE 7/5 plug to any other plug, then find an adapter from that plug to the Israeli SI-32 plug. Or just find a direct adapter, though I couldn't find any such thing.

Alternatively, buy an Israeli plug, cut off the French plug, and wire in the Israeli plug in its place. If you're not planning on taking the appliance out of Israel at any time, that might be easier.

All the adapters I saw did not have the fixed male grounding pin that the French plug relies on for its ground connection. Perhaps they would make a connection between their center ground and the metal around the pinhole, but I don't know.

Comment: Adapters that properly handle grounding seem a bit rare, and stacking adapters to power a heating appliance makes me nervous. I recommend finding a repair plug locally and replacing the French plug as JW Sherman suggests.

Comment: @bcworkz Philips is against DIY and replacing plug at all. Manual says that if power cord is damaged, refer to local Philips authorized repair center or at least authorized dealer.

Comment: @Boris_yo - it's just a liability thing. If they didn't say that, and you modified it, and something bad happened, they would get sued.   This way, they say "don't do it" so that when you do it, you are going against what they suggested and it's your fault not theirs.

Comment: It now hit me that EU plug can be turned upside down to match Israeli socket. What remains is to attach protruding pin so it can reach G in socket. The only issue might be N and L because they would be switched places.

Comment: This plug is suitable for two systems; the French system with a ground pin in the socket, and the German system with ground clamps at the top and bottom. The German system is used in all EU countries except France and Denmark. There should be plenty of adapter between the German (Schuko) system and the Israeli.

Comment: @Orbit That's not true, at least Czechia and Slovakia are on the "French" system (Type E) as well, Ireland uses British plugs and Italy has the weird one with three pins in a row. (There might be more, I've not been to all EU countries.)

Comment: @TooTea: You are right. I didn't remember right, I got my info here though: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schuko

Answer (score 3):

Cut off the plug and replace it with an Israeli plug; it's quick and easy—in fact, it was something they taught us in middle school when we were on a field trip to the local power company.

An alternative could be to buy a new cord with the Israeli plug attached, and then replace the entire cord.

Answer (score -1):

The safest options are:
1> Buy a new plug according to your country standard and replace it.
2> If you have some stuff requiring CE 7/4: install a Schuko [German] (type 7) or French (type 4) outlet in your home to accomodate your devices with such plug (In Italy we often have the combo German/Italian because most of the appliances are sold with german plug.

The last and less safe option is to get an adapter.

Comment: You do realize this question is 10 years old and you've repeated the advice given in both the other answers, right?

Comment: It's true... I've seen it in first page and answered without checking the age